# Kirchhoff’s rules

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

Can Kirchhoff’s rules be applied to simple series and parallel circuits or are they restricted for use in more complicated circuits that are not combinations of series and parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirchhoff's circuit laws are two equalities that deal with the current and potential difference (commonly known as voltage) in electrical circuits.

They do not care whether your circuit is simple series, parallel, or some complicated circuit. You can use them wherever you want to, but of course, it's useless to use them in a place where it's simple to analyze the circuit with simple algebra.